# Git not working on my repository. I can't push nor commit from any new branches I create

Tags: git, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUOJg.png)When I try to push, it says I have nothing to commit.

When I try to commit, it says it's a clean commit with no changes, which isn't true.

When I try an empty commit, it still gives the above error and pushes nothing.

The branch then randomly shows in my github saying there's no changes between the branch and the main, which isn't true!!!!!! The branch is obviously edited and I even checked. The index.js file inside the branch has the updates JS but the main branch doesn't but it won't take the pull request because it doesn't acknowledge the changes. I'm so ready to never touch git again.

Here's my repo : https://github.com/ThatDevDiaz/rock-paper-scissors-game

I've tried opening a branch from github directly and pushing remotely, says the branch doesn't exist.

I've tried opening a branch from my terminal, then I get the errors in the first 2 lines I wrote.

I've tried fetching, and pulling, then making changes, it still says no changes to be made, which again, isn't true.

My local repo is updated, and my remote repo just refuses to take my local branches or my local changes for whatever reason. It's just outright refusing to acknowledge my changes. I've spent 2 days on forums and using Chat GPT, etc to figure this out, and i'm stuck in a never ending loop of my local repo not pushing to my remote repo.

Yes i'm logged in, yes git remote -v acknowledges my branches, yes I've done the whole git init + git add . + git commit -m a million times over. I've tried everything I can find online. It still won't work. I'm so freaking frustrated with git right now. I haven't had this problem with any of my other repos. I'm desperate for some help here to do this the right way instead of just re-uploading the project to a new repo.

Comment: Can you post `git status` output? Ideally it should show that you have some changes staged for the commit. If you have, `git commit` should work. If not, `git add <file>`.

Comment: @MaciejDobosz game-main> 
game-main> git status
On branch restart-game
nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Users\CesarDiaz\OneDrive\Documents\coding\rock-paper-scissors-game-main>

Comment: @matt What does that even mean? I understand you might have lots of industry experience, but I don't. I downloaded my own project, created the branch in github, and pushed to the branch. I'm asking for assistance here because the information in front of me is not making sense. I'm happy that it clicks so easily for you, but not everybody has the experience you have. I'm working inside the same project so why would it not acknowledge the changes between main and restart-game?? I push how I did with my last few repositories. I did nothing different this time, but suddenly it doesn't work.

Comment: "I've spent 2 days on forums and using Chat GPT"—ChatGPT is _not intelligent_. Don't trust it.

Comment: I find the UI of GitHub is quite confusing for inspecting the state of my repositories. I suggest you use `gitk --all` locally to see what you are doing (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk/).

Comment: I pay for GPT4. I understand it's not the best resource, it's just a resource to cross-reference other resources. It's taught me a lot of things and showed me different approaches I haven't seen before, so I don't want to disregard it entirely.

Comment: "You made a branch without branching off the existing main branch"

I didn't even know this was possible. If I knew that, I wouldn't have asked. Thanks to @maciejDobosz comment, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and tried to do `git merge main` from the `restart-game` branch. It failed with `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` - seems like `restart-game` wasn't checked out from `main` branch? In order to fix this I would do:

```
git rebase main
<fix conflicts in files>
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

I ended up with `restart-game` being two commits in front of `main`. In order to merge it to main, you would do:

```
git checkout main
git merge restart-game
```

You also mentioned problems with commits not being created. This is what I would do to test if everything works:

```
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Commited text.txt"
git log
```

This will create a test.txt file and commit it.

Comment: "seems like restart-game wasn't checked out from main branch?"

This comment was the epiphany I needed. I started the process incorrectly which led to this issue. Now I know how to properly create the branch on my own repositories to avoid this issue. 

I cloned my project using this advice and just copy-pasted the changes over. Resolved.

Thank you for the answer